# separate home page into separate pages

Tags: themes, pages

I was recently asked to help out with a [site](http://www.cascadepacific.org/lfc-wp/) where, as you can see, all the content is on one page.  As it's less than elegant, I'd like to separate things out but I've looked around the menus and settings, I can't find anything obvious.

If I click the "pages" link on the left side, I'm taken to a list of seemingly separate pages.  When I click the "edit" button that appears after I roll over the page, I can edit just the content associated with that page (tho again, it's all on one page on the site - maybe I'm misunderstanding terminology).  However, if I click "view" I get a server error.

In fact, I get a lot of server/404 errors when clicking around the dashboard/other menu items.  For example, if I click "Page Order" and then reorder pages and then click "Click to Reorder Pages" I'm taken to the site but with a "Four Oh Four Error".

Another error - if I change the Settings > Reading Settings setting `Front Page Displays` from `Your Latest Posts` to `a static page` I get another server error.

I could go on, but I'll leave it at that for now.  (I can always add more to the comments.)

Any help or pointers would be much appreciated.  And if you feel like throwing in a link that will help me understand WordPress's structure, that'd be great.  I come from an Programming background which should hopefully help.

Comment: Screenshots of the problematic areas if possible?

Comment: WordPress Structure http://codex.wordpress

Comment: If you need help with a new design I can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

..are they using the latest version of WordPress? If not, upgrade. Also, see if the problem continues after switching to the default "Twenty Eleven" WordPress theme.

Comment: Yes indeed, WordPress 3.4.2
And they're using ShapeShifter as the Theme.
I'll trying switching.

Comment: Changing the theme did it.  I suppose I'll look through some theme's now to find the best one.

Comment: Ok great. Make sure everything works properly now. Tell your friend they'll have to part with their Shape Shifting buddy.

Comment: Free Premium themes http://www.web2feel.com

Comment: If you need more help, just ask another question or search through ones already answered.